# What is the best way to use MYSQL Search on term not working

Tags: mysql

What is the best way to search a database for a phrase such as "Almond Anise Cookie" and return the result?

If I

```
SELECT * 
FROM recipes 
WHERE name LIKE '%".$query."%'
```

and use the phrase "Almond Cookie", nothing is returned as expected.  But if I search for "Anise Cookie" the result above is returned.

I've also tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM recipes 
WHERE name LIKE '%".$query."%' 
OR name LIKE '".$query."%' 
OR name LIKE '%".$query."'
```

with the same failed result.

Using `MATCH AGAINST` returns everything that contains "Almond" and everything that contains "Cookie" also not a good result.  Is there a happy middle in returned results?

Comment: Please show the real code, as this is obviously written for PHP or something. What you show is just so obviously syntactically incorrect

Comment: ?? _the result above is returned_ ?? What result above. The real code please

Comment: Why should MySQL return a row that contains "Almond Anise Cookie" if you search for "Almond Cookie"? That row does not contain the search term

Comment: This will search for the occurrence of whatever the phrase stored in $query is. For example if $query = "Almond Cookie" and the title is "Almond Anise Cookie", it should return nothing. If you want to search every word individually, you should explode the string and search with the OR modifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `REPLACE`. Something like this should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM recipes 
WHERE NAME LIKE REPLACE(' ".$query." ',' ','%');
```

Note that I purposely add spaces between `.$query.` to ensure that the replace operation will make your term filled with the wildcard symbol. In the example above:

If `$query`='almond cookies' then `REPLACE(' ".$query." ',' ','%')` will become `%almond%cookies%`.

You can test the fiddle here : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kMzp99S8ENbTkYcW5FVdYN/0

Comment: tcadidot0 Worked, and appreciate your help!